# Creating and Using a Java package without Eclipse

Tags: java, oop, package

I know this is a basic question. I've been working with Java for a long time... However today I suddenly thought about creating a package without an IDE. So I thought the following should have worked :

```
package test;

class Node {

    int data;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

class SumBinaryTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ////
    }
}
```

Now, I thought that now package test contained class Node and class SumBinaryTree. After doing `javac SumBinaryTree.java`, I wrote the following code :

```
package test;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node t = new Node(0);
    }    
}
```

Now, since `package test;` is present, I thought this would work. However, on doing `javac Test.java`, I got an error with the two Node lines. I then realized that I did not know what was correctly going on and could use some help understanding this from you guys!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using `javac SumBinaryTree.java Test.java`?

Comment: ...You have a very wrong / incomplete model of how Java compilation and running works. At a guess, I think the official tutorial on packages might be useful to you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/ Also relevant is the tutorial on the *class path* (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and the technical note it links to (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: This is how exactly programming was done in earlier days before IDE got in. Well try going out of the directory and then compile. `javac test/Test.java` and then run as `java test/Test`.

Comment: Look at the examples section in the javac documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#examples

Comment: @H-Patel I'd dispute the historical claim. I'd say programming was done using some form of automated tooling for a very long time, insofar as it makes obvious sense for a programmer to be able to reproduce building a nontrivial program reliably. If it wasn't an IDE as we know it it was Emacs and a Makefile, or a bunch of shellscripts and utilities to manage things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the package-

```
javac test/*.java
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in your command line

```
    cd intoParentDirWhereNodeIs
    javac Node.java
    javac -d . Node.java
```

This should create a folder package called test in your files